# Formatting a file name when using %1$s

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Anyone help me with a formatting issue I have? I have a relative file path that my app uses to copy the file over and save it, such as:

```
\users\user1\test.pdf
```

Only problem is if you use `%1$s` as your formatter string it will copy this file over as a folder and then save the file in that folder, so you end up with the file name as part of the path, such as:

```
\users\user1\test.pdf\test.pdf
```

Anyone know the correct format string to get around this?

Comment: I think you're going to need some code context here, but it seems to me that you're redundantly putting the file name into the path when whatever "save" function you have already inserts the filename correctly.

Comment: Please post some code so that we have a context as to how you are saving your files. 

os.path may have the answer to your problem: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Comment: Is the asker still checking for responses to this message? I'd love to help out but like previous commenters said, we're going to need more code context.

Comment: I solved this by changing the original paths that were indexed not to contain the file name, worked fine. I didn't find any way to strip the file name out just using formatter patterns.

Comment: @user898465, if your problem is solved, kindly post your own answer and accept it unless you are waiting for newer answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use File objects for handling paths.

```
File f = new File("test/something");

f.getParent();
f.getName();

etc...
```